# Removing part of text from Table column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A website I am host was recently SQL injected, and I want to find a way to remove the offending injected code from a particular column (comments) in the database. Using SQL Server 2008, I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
USE Dirty
SELECT REPLACE(comments,'</title><script src=http://hjfghj.com/r.php ></script>','')
FROM SALONS
```

Comment: What **datatype** is `Comments` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only selecting - not updating....

Try this:

```
USE Dirty

UPDATE dbo.Salons
SET Comments = REPLACE(comments,'</title><script src=http://hjfghj.com/r.php ></script>','')
WHERE (possibly a condition here...)
```

Comment: I'm getting:  Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: You should be using nvarchar(max) instead of ntext as your column time. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) You may have to change quite a bit of code, depending on how you handled your ntext columns, but it will be worth it.

Comment: You should be using nvarchar(max) instead of ntext as your column type. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) You may have to change quite a bit of code, depending on how you handled your ntext columns, but it will be worth it.

Comment: @user547794: that's why I had asked what datatype that column is. `NTEXT` cannot be manipulated using the "normal" string functions - and it's deprecated, you should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually updating anything, merely selecting it.  You need to create an update statement

```
USE Dirty

UPDATE SALONS
    SET comments = REPLACE(comments,'</title><script src=http://hjfghj.com/r.php ></script>','')
```

Comment: I got:  Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Answer (score -1):

Because the column was "ntext" that was causing an error.  I managed to fix this with using a cast like this:

```
USE Dirty
    UPDATE dbo.Salons
    SET Comments = cast(replace(cast(comments as varchar(8000)),'</title><script src=http://hjfghj.com/r.php ></script>','') as ntext)
```

Comment: If you do this - make sure to cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` !!!! Otherwise, you're limiting your comments to 8000 characters, and you're converting them back to non-Unicode, too!!